# Unable to connect access IP webcam

Tags: pi-3, python, opencv, webcam

I'm trying to access my phone camera using IP Webcam android app. I'm programming Pi using my laptop via Remote Desktop Connection with a static IP set for Pi. Also I tried to stream webcam from Pi's chromium browser showing connection timed out. I'm able to stream the cam from my laptop's Firefox browser.

Code given below is throwing some error.

```
import urllib
import cv2
import numpy as np

url='http://192.168.225.51:8080/shot.jpg'

while True:
    imgResp=urllib.urlopen(url)
    imgNp=np.array(bytearray(imgResp.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
    img=cv2.imdecode(imgNp,-1)

    # all the opencv processing is done here
    cv2.imshow('test',img)
    if ord('q')==cv2.waitKey(10):
        exit(0)=
```

The following error is shown

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/New.py", line 8, in <module>
    imgResp=urllib.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 350, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1038, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 882, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 844, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 821, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

> Also I tried to stream webcam from Pi's chromium browser showing connection timed out.

This is the core of your problem: **the Pi has no access to the camera over the network**. You need to diagnose your network and find out what's wrong. I would start by running

```
traceroute 192.168.225.51
```

to see how data is routed.

Comment: It's showing the following things only.
    `traceroute to 192.168.225.51 (192.168.225.51), 30 hops max, 60     byte packets
     1  * * *
     2  * * *
     3  * * *
    .........`

Comment: What's your Pi's IP address? How does the routing table (`route -n`) look like?

Comment: Pi's IP is 192.168.137.55

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface 
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.137.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0`

_I'm not able to paste above info in correct format please view in editor_